# Regex to select specific characters inside HTML tags

Tags: python, regex

I'm only looking for standard tags like p, title, h1, h2 etc.

```
<[/a]*>content resides in here</[/a]*>
```

And I'm specifically looking for punctuation marks to combat a potential SQL injection. Also, for this project I am unable to use BeautifulSoup.

Comment: You may want to read: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Have you looked into [```HTMLParser```](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)?

Comment: Why are you unable to use BeautifulSoup? It's pure Python (so it works anywhere Python itself works without the need for external tools) and it's MIT-licensed (so you can use it in commercial software).

Comment: Why validate when you can sanitize more easily? Do you not want escaped quote characters in your SQL queries?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
<(a|h1|p|title)[^>]*>([^<]+)</\1[^>]*>
```

#### Discussion

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/mB4bQ1

#### Discussion

I assume that tags will contain text only, no tags...
Python doesn't support recursive regular expression.